# how to select uniquely users that try to login more that 10 times on the internet

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, c#-4.0

I currently developed a web site that my user must login to web site. When a user comes I create a `Session` for him/her and save number of time + time of unsuccessful logins for him.When user try 5 time login I show him a `CAPTCHA` and force him to enter `CAPTCHA` code.Now I want when user try more that 10 times, redirect him in an simple `HTML` file that show him that *`You are ban for 2 hours`*.The problem is how I can select unique user in internet? What information about user together can select a unique user?

Comment: Reliably?  Good luck with that.  There's no way that can't be forged by a user with the right browser.  Well, short of IP banning, but even that causes trouble with proxies, anonymizers...basically anyone who's sharing an IP.

Comment: unrelated - [CAPTCHA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) has a "T"

Comment: so you are right but it can decrease the risk of attacks.does not it?

Comment: @Kerezo it can also decrease the risk of many of your genuine users being able to log in to your site. IMO, better to just track login attempts on account records, so you can detect brute-force attacks.

Comment: I have a link for `Forgot Password` so user can use it before 10 try

Comment: @Kerezo yes, but you are asking "unique user in internet", suggesting a unique *real person*. The "Forgot Password" works at the account level - great; so just use that and count failed attempts per account. Your intent here is likely to be much more of an inconvenience to **real users** (on proxies etc) than it is to attackers; knowledgeable attackers will have the tools (disparate proxies etc) to work around it trivially. Real users won't. You punish the real folks and don't hardly inconvenience your intended attackers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking the user to log in, so it sounds like you already have a unique login ID for each user, and your underlying concern is to prevent a malicious user from subverting your system into locking out a different valid user while still stopping them from password cracking.  Is that correct?

You cannot with absolute certainty prevent a malicious user from using your intrusion protection scheme to interfere with other users.  If you see what appears to be someone attempting to brute-force another user's password, then you can lock out that IP address for some duration... or possibly just that IP address for that account... but you run the risk of a malicious user behind a shared IP of a NAT gateway causing all other users behind that same gateway to be locked out.  Any information sent to your server can be spoofed, so it's a bit of a balancing act.  A combination of user ID and IP address wouln't be infallable in terms of representing a unique individual, but it would be enough to prevent most common abuses.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the username in the site to be unique, you could use the combination of username and session to block the particular user.
If the user uses the same username from different machines 10 times , it can be blocked.

Comment: yes but if user be a *bad man* and he/she try usernames that don't exist what can I do?

Comment: every other malicious attack cannot be determined beforehand , just the most probable must be handled.